# Retrieve Deleted Project in MS Visual SourceSafe?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

A while ago, I "tidied up" our Visual SourceSafe repository, including deleting a duplicate of one project.  It now turns out that the duplicate had some code I need to see.

How can I get back a deleted project?

I can't see from any of the docs how to do this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is there on Microsoft's site:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244019.

- Select the project which is the parent of the deleted project.
- Right-click and select "Properties..."
- Select the "Deleted Items" tab.

  - This displays all deleted files *and* projects under the specified project
- Select the project you want to get back
- Click "Recover"
- All Done.

Answer (score 2):

I hope, for your sake, that you resisted the urge to check the "Delete Permanently" checkbox when you removed the project. It's too easy to check, and there's no way to recover from that, short of restoring a physical sourcesafe backup.

Comment: That's a great tip.  thanks!  
I don't tick that checkbox, but I agree - it's all too tempting!